# Passing Objects into PHP constructor error

Tags: php, syntax, scope, object-properties

Is it possible to pass an object into the constructor of a PHP class, and set that object as a global variable that can be used by the rest of the functions in the class?

For example:

```
class test {

   function __construct($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) {
      global $DB, $ode, $sel;

      $DB = arg1;
      $ode = arg2;
      $sel = $arg3;
   }

   function query(){
      $DB->query(...);
   }

}
```

When I try to do this, I get a "Call to a member function on a non-object" error. Is there anyway to do this? Otherwise, I have to pass the objects into each individual function directly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to assign them to values on `$this`.

In your constructor, you'd do:

```
$this->DB = $arg1;
```

Then in your query function:

```
$this->DB->query(...);
```

This should similarly be done with the other arguments to your constructor.

`$this` in an instance context is how you reference the current instance. There's also keywords `parent::` and `self::` to access members of the superclass and static members of the class, respectively.

Comment: That works, thanks for your help! What if I want to do the same thing with non-objects as well? Let's say I want to pass in an integer or a string?

Comment: Works the same way. You can put any fields you want on $this, so long as it's a valid identifier (similar to valid variable names).  So you would do `$this->name = "somestring";` or `$this->name = $name;` etc. This is not limited to the constructor, any methods on the class can modify fields on `$this`.

Comment: Just for the sake of your code's clarity, add this: private $db = null; and then place a comment on it (maybe not really necessary since $db should tell you the purpose of the property) :)

Answer (score 3):

As a side-note...
Even thought this isn't *required*, it is generally considered best to *declare* member variables inside the class. It gives you better control over them:

```
<?php
class test {
    // Declaring the variables.
    // (Or "members", as they are known in OOP terms)
    private $DB;
    protected $ode;
    public $sel;

    function __construct($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) {
      $this->DB = arg1;
      $this->ode = arg2;
      $this->sel = $arg3;
    }

    function query(){
      $this->DB->query(...);
    }
}
?>
```

See [PHP: Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) for details on the difference between `private`, `protected` and `public`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it pretty easily by storing the argument as a property of the object:

```
function __construct($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) {
   $this->db = arg1;
}

function f()
{
  $this->db->query(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

let's say you have a db object

```
$db = new db();
```

and another object:

```
$object = new object($db);

class object{

    //passing $db to constructor
    function object($db){

       //assign it to $this
       $this-db = $db;

    }

     //using it later
    function somefunction(){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

        $this->db->query($sql);

    }

}
```